# Error in Correlation Matrix: why deleting NA still doesn't work?

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation, na, numeric

I'm trying to make the correlation matrix

Here a sample of the dataset.

```
> head(matrix)
# A tibble: 6 x 16
# Groups:   nquest, nord [6]
  nquest  nord   sex anasc  ireg   eta staciv studio asnonoc2 nace2 nesplav etalav dislav acontrib occnow tpens
   <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>  <int> <fct>     <int> <int> <fct>   <fct>  <fct>     <int>  <int> <int>
1    173     1     1  1948    18    72      3 2             2    19 1       2      0            35      2  1800
2   2886     1     1  1949    13    71      1 2             2    16 1       2      0            35      2  1211
3   2886     2     0  1952    13    68      1 3             2    17 1       2      0            42      2  2100
4   5416     1     0  1958     8    62      3 1             1    19 2       1      0            30      2   700
5   7886     1     1  1950     9    70      1 2             2    11 1       2      0            35      2  2000
6  20297     1     1  1960     5    60      1 1             1    19 2       1      0            39      2  1200
```

Actually, `nquest` and `nord` are identification codes: the first is for the family, the second for the member of that specific family. Even if I try to remove them (because I think they are useless in a correlation matrix), dplyr add them automatically

```
matrix <- final %>%
           select("sex", "anasc", "ireg", "eta","staciv", "studio", "asnonoc2", 
                  "nace2", "nesplav", "etalav", "dislav", "acontrib", "occnow",
                  "tpens")
```

Dplyr answers

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `nquest`, `nord`
```

However, I don't think it is a problem if they remain in the dataset.

My goal is to compute the correlation matrix, but this dataset seems to have some NA values

```
> sum(is.na(matrix))
[1] 109
```

I've tried these codes, but none of them works.

The first

```
cor(matrix, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

R replies

```
Error in cor(matrix, use = "pairwise.complete.obs") : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

The second

```
cor(na.omit(matrix))
```

R answers

```
Error in cor(na.omit(matrix)) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I've also tried

```
matrix <- as.numeric(matrix)
```

But I get another kind of error

```
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How can I solve?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually in your matrix `studio, nesplav, etalav, dislav` are factor not numeric. Try calculating correlation after removing the factor variables.

Comment: `matrix` or rather `final` is grouped. Try `final %>% ungroup() %>% select ...`

Comment: hi @UseR10085 and thank for the answer ! if I try `matrix <- as.numeric(matrix$etalav)` R replies `Error in matrix$etalav : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` How can I solve?

Comment: hi @AndreWildberg thank for the explanation. I'm pretty new in this kind of things.... what does it mean that they are grouped? Aren't the rows referred to specific individuals?

Comment: E.g. `group_by(group)`, if column `group` has repeated values, treats data as blocks and calculations like sum or mean are applied to these groups. See `?dplyr::group_by`

Comment: @AndreWildberg ok thank! I'm gonna study this topic. Do you have any idea how to create the correlation matrix here?

Comment: I'd guess you want something like `cor(as.matrix(matrix))` after you removed the unwanted columns.

Comment: You can drop the factor variables before calculating correlation. Use `matrix <- final %>% select("sex", "anasc", "ireg", "eta","staciv", "asnonoc2", "nace2",  "acontrib", "occnow", "tpens")` then `cor(matrix, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")`

Comment: Also note that your factors possibly cast to character so be sure to convert them to numeric prior to any calculation.

Comment: @UseR10085 removing the factors the correlation matrix works

Comment: @AndreWildberg i've tried to convert these factors in number with `matrix <- as.numeric(matrix$etalav)`, but R replies `Error in matrix$etalav : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` Where is the error in this code?

Comment: `matrix` is a vector. `$` chooses columns/lists and vectors don't have any.

Comment: @AndreWildberg   I've thought `matrix` was a sort of dataframe. In R studios I've `matrix` as `tbl_df` . Is tibble 6 x 16 a vector? I was sure vector was just the single column of the dataframe...

Comment: `matrix` is your object named "matrix". That's an unfortunate name to begin with and has nothing to do with an object that is a matrix. `class(matrix)` in your case will show `numeric` or `character`. See the difference in `class(matrix(1:6, ncol=2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be in the type of your data columns. In your example some of your data columns are of type `factor` (indicated as `<fct>` in your data like `studio` for example). They are actually `numeric` but currently of  `factor` type in your dataset for some unknown reasons. Therefore they are recognized by the `cor()` function as string type and not numeric resulted in throwing the error. So, you might need to convert your data type into their numeric format for correlation analysis. One option is to use `type.convert()`. If you have columns of type `character` (like string values) they must be removed from the data to be used for correlation analysis. Also as was suggested by commenters would be better to not use reserved names in R for your objects like `matrix` in your example. Here is my advise:

```
# copy your data into dft
dft<-matrix

#return the type of variables into their actual type
dft <- type.convert(dft,as.is=TRUE)

# perform correlation excluding first two columns as you explained not informative
cor(dft[,-c(1:2)],use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Hope it could helps

Comment: hi @SALAR and thank for the answer! I've coverted those variables ( `studio, nesplav, etalav, dislav`) as factors to use them in a linear regression model ( thery were ordinal categorical variables). Your code works fine! Thank for the help and for the explanation